# Miracast/Chromecast from ChromeBook to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, chromebook, google-chrome-os, chromecast, miracast

I am attempting to Extend my ChromeBook laptop's screen (not Mirror) to a Windows laptop screen wirelessly via Chromecast or Miracast.

This should be simple, as they both possess the hardware to perform casting, and easily connect to each other via Bluetooth.

However, the Windows laptop does not show up in the Chromecast "Cast" tab on the Chromebook. (And the Chromebook does not show up on the Windows Laptop's "Connect to a wireless display" page.)

I have already modified the Windows settings for "Projecting to this PC." Everything is turned on.

All search results I can find only explain how to Chromecast from Windows, cast to a Smart TV, or other common uses. I did find this article on Miracasting using Chromium, but it is more scholarly than instructional.

What am I missing?

Comment: One thinh you're missing is that you can't extend, even if you manage to cast.

Comment: How do you mean? I have successfully used Miracast to extend a Windows computer display using another Windows computer. I have seen articles claiming you can use Chromecast on Windows to extend your display, but that is not what I am trying to do.